# Is there a way to ignore file permissions in the Shared folder?

Tags: finder, photos, permission, user-account, sharing

I have a Mac (Big Sur 11.6.6) set up with two user accounts. Each has their own folder in `Users` and there's a folder called `Shared` that both have access to.

One of my workflows involves syncing photos by exporting from the Photos app in one account and importing in the other. The issue I'm having is that when I export photos in Alice's account, the new files show up owned by Alice with `No Access` for `everyone`. As you'd expect, Photos fails with errors when I try to import them in Bob's account.

Both accounts are admins so the workaround I've been using is to use the Finder's `Duplicate` in Bob's account, which prompts for an admin login and password every time. I then have a copy owned by Bob. Alternatively I could open the terminal and use chmod or chown. Or I could set the whole volume to ignore ownership, but then the users private folders would no longer be private.

Is there anything I can set that would make the `Shared` folder actually shared, so I don't need to constantly enter login/password to use files put there by another user?

Update - I just discovered that if I use the regular `Export` command instead of `Export Unmodified Original`, the files are set to `Read` for `everyone` and the problem doesn't occur. But I still want to be able to use `Export Unmodified Original`.

Comment: When I do the export the files are Everyone - Read. Suspect your issue is due to ownership and permissions on /Users/Shared or the folder into which you are exporting.

Comment: @Gilby Just checked and /Users/Shared is Everyone - Read and Write for Everyone. But I noticed that when I use "Export Photos" they come out Everyone - Read, while when I use "Export Unmodified Original" they come out Everyone - No Access. So I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Even with "Export Unmodified Original" they come out Everyone - Read Only. Don't know why that is different to your experiance. I am going to leave someone else to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Gilby Weird! Thank you for your help.